# Eclipse Upgrade & Nothing Showing

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I was using an older version of eclipse with an older JDK, JRE and now trying to upgrade to a newer version of eclipse I can not see new packages or the interfaces that should show the .java files. I have tried making a new workspace and import doesn't work, even without old files nothing in the package explorer is visible.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `File -> Switch Workspace -> Other...` and then choose your other workspace?

Comment: Yes and this does not help at all the interfaces seem to be all blank.

Comment: What about creating a new Java Project?

Comment: Yes it's interfaces are still bugged, tried re downloading and lower version but still bugged out.